# Removal of bountiful user: does it affect your reputation?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone confirm: if a bounty has been awarded to you by a user that is subsequently removed then do you lose that reputation gain due to the bounty?

(To provide context; if that user has upvoted net *a* of your answers and net *q* questions, then you would lose *10a + 5q*. But are the bounty amounts removed too?)

Comment: I thought bounties are removed from the user when offered, and they go into a void if not rewarded to anyone. Based on this, I would make a guess and say the user no longer owns the reputation from the point of offering, so it should be fine, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a bounty, once earned, is not removed again when the account that set the bounty has been removed.

A bounty is paid *to the system* as advertisement for a question. If you then earned that bounty, it was paid to you by the system (either with approval from the person setting the bounty or automatically). It is not a vote from the user, and is thus not removed with account deletions.

If the *answer* that earned the bounty is deleted, you do lose the reputation earned, including the bounty amount. When an account is deleted, any questions with a negative score by that user are automatically deleted, and that *can* lead to an answer with an earned bounty  to be deleted as well.

Comment: The awarding user is listed, though - in this case, it is changed from the original user to Community.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, which also happens when the account is deleted before the bounty is awarded.

Comment: How can Community issue so many bounties with no rep!?!?! Hmm... maybe that's why it has no rep... @BoltClock